# Adding multiple textviews to horizontal linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

Hi i am running a loop 10 times and each time i am creating a new TextView and I am adding that textview to my Linear layout which has orientation set to 'HORIZONTAL'. I want to show these texts in the form of paragraph where another sentence starts form where one sentence ends.

This is my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.QuestionActivity"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_question">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/base_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my java code:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        TextView textView = Utility.getTextView(this, i);

        if(i == 5) {
            textView.setText(sentences.get(i) + "\n" + "\n");
        }
        else {
            textView.setText(sentences.get(i) + " ");
        }

        mLayout.addView(textView);
    }
```

But the issue is only first textview is shown when orientation is set to 'horizontal' and if i set my orientation to 'vertical' i am able to see all textviews below one another.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you try to set orientation grammatically.?

Comment: Not working tried thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should need to wrap your base_layout `LinearLayout` under `HorizontalScrollView`.

Try below, should solve your issue. I have verified myself.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal">

      <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/base_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Krishna Sharma but that would mean my textviews will be horizontally scrollable which i don't want, i want to show them in the form of paragraph

Comment: then all textviews will not get display **horizontally** in the screen. That's what happening in your case.

Comment: So how should i work around this? and may i know reason why they are not getting displayed

Comment: only the option is orientation **vertical**. If you want horizontally then you must need to wrap your layout under horizontal scroll view.

Comment: if you remove ScrollView from your layout then even for vertical orientation all textviews will not get display. Anyway you you need to have scrolling doesn't matter whether it is vertical or horizontal.

Comment: can you please specify reason why it's not working with horizontal orientation

Comment: Device screen width and height is limited, so if we add views and all views doesn't fit into the screen then how all them will get display.

Comment: any property which i can set here to textviews that displays the remaining text in next line if it is not fitted?

Comment: Why you want to add views horizontally ? do you have any design how that you want your app look like. Better to attach screenshot of your design.

Comment: Yes just show 10 sentences in the form of a paragraph

Comment: Example will help to understand the requirement.